# React-Redux-Router - Firing action to load details page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a react-redux app with a List of items. Each item has a button to open a detail.

So when the detail is click, I have something like:

```
dispatch(push(`/items/$item_id`)
```

This has a route configured:

```
  <Route path="/item/edit/:id" component={ItemEdit} />
```

What I missing is how to fetch the item data when the new route is hit. I know is trivial in componentWillMount or componentWillReceiveProps, but they are abstracted by redux.connect.

I need an action to be fired when the path has changed or is about to change for this component.

The only way I see is using:

```
BrowserHistory.listen(location => dispatch(routeLocationDidUpdate(location)));
```

But this seems ugly because it shares the behavioud of all components. ie, I would need a switch like (

```
routeLocationUpdate(location) {
  switch(location)
    case path1: dispatch(load_item) 
    case path2: dispach(load_talks)
    ...
```

Sorry if not clear enough.

thanks
fernando

Comment: Dispatch an action that does more than just push a change to the history state. Look into thunks or sagas. I would advise that you don't put application logic inside event listeners on `BrowserHistory`.

Comment: Sorry, reading several examples I found that <Route ...> has a onEnter hook with do exactly what I want.